# Closing/Disposing two forms at once after logging in

Tags: java, forms, swing, dispose

So the Login.java (first form) is like a homepage then a `JButton` "Start" is in the middle of the Login.java which appears the LoginStudent.java where the user enters their email and password. Therefore both forms are on `setVisible(true)`

The problem is after logging on in LoginStudent.java, yes the form closed however the Login.java didn't closed. It just displayed behind the dashboard.

I did try the `Login a = new Login();` which links to the first form or the Login.java. Here's the code I input:

```
/**
logging in using ENTER key, same code to jButtonActionPerformed
I'm using JFrame Form
**/

private void passTextKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){ 

Login a = new Login();

if (rs.getString("type").equals("STUDENT")) {
        studentDashboard std = new studentDashboard();
        std.setVisible(true); //this appears the dashboard after logging in
        this.dispose();
        a.dispose(); //also tried the a.setVisible(false); 
                        
                    } 
     }
}
```

I'm still a second year student college studying under Information Technology and I don't know a lot yet. I'm working on a system database out of hobby.

Comment: A login form is a good [use case for a `CardLayout`](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/64-java-login-with-cardlayout)

Comment: How does the Login.java look like?

Comment: To continue what @g00se posted, ".... or a modal JDialog".  Also, do you call `setDefaultCloseOperation(....)` and what argument do you pass in?